# Stop automatic reordering of documents in mongo db

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, mongoose

When I add any subdocument to an existing document, the documents are rearranged in **mongo db**.

The result of the query is assigned to a model in angularjs code.Which results in changing of orders of data in view.

How do I stop this automatic rearranging of documents?

I can see these documents rearrange in **Robomongo** when ever I make any change.
So I can surely say that the objects are rearranged in disk when ever they are updated.

Am I doing something wrong or the documents are automatically rearranging.

Code:

Here allusersposts comes from controller when the page loads.

```
var basePost1 = Restangular.all('posts');

basePost1.getList().then(function(allusersposts) {
$scope.allusersposts = allusersposts;

});
```

Mark up:

```
    <div class="list-group" data-ng-repeat="usersposts in allusersposts" >

            <h4>{{usersposts.description}}</h4>
            <!--                    ng repeat for comments on each post -->             
            <div class="list-group" data-ng-repeat="eachcomment in usersposts.comments ">

                <label>{{eachcomment.description}}</label>

            </div>
            <!--input comment -->
            <textarea rows="3" data-ng-model='comment'></textarea>
            <button data-ng-click="saveComment(usersposts,comment)" >comment</button>
        </div>
```

When comment is added to any post then I save the comment in db and then bring back all the posts again and assign it to $scope.allusersposts. Which causes view to order of the posts is not the same as before.The post to which comment was added moves to some other location in list.

```
$scope.saveComment=function(usersposts,comment){
    var post_id=usersposts._id;
    var basePost = Restangular.one('getSinglepost', post_id);

    basePost.get().then(function(receiveSinglePost) {
        var basePost = Restangular.one('getSinglepost', post_id);
        var makePutdata={
            'description':comment,
            'user_id':$stateParams._id


        }

        basePost.put(makePutdata).then(function(allPosts) {
            $scope.allusersposts=allPosts;

        });

    });
$scope.comment="";


};
```

Comment: Post some code.  What 'change' are you making that causes the re-ordering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's down to disk storage allocation for that collection.  Mongo will attempt to replace the old document with the new one if it can do in the allocated space, but if it can't, it'll expire the old document and save the updated document onto the end of the collection on disk.

When you call find() on a collection, it will work from the beginning to the end of the disk storage, because this is most efficient.  There is no guarantee of this being the same as insertion order if you have subsequently modified any documents.

If you want to have consistent output, sort by some key like a createdTimestamp when you fetch from the collection.  You should probably also add an index on this field.

Comment: added sort by _id to all find() queries and its working fine.Thank you.